# Type Conversion Issue(?): How to grab html <span> tag's value and perform math on it?

Tags: javascript, type-conversion

How would I use javascript to take 30% off of the price and then append the discounted price under the old price? I'm getting tripped up on this.

Someone advised that I need to remove the $ some other way...?

**HTML**

```
<span class="price">$59.00</span>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var priceOne = parseInt(document.querySelector(".price").innerHTML);
var priceTwo = "$" + priceOne * .70;
document.querySelector(".price").innerHTML = priceTwo;
```

All tips or advice or solutions is appreciated!

Comment: Did you check what is your `priceOne` after `parseInt`? It is `NaN`

Answer (score 0):

```js
let oriprice = document.getElementById('price').innerHTML;

    let priceOne = parseFloat(oriprice.substring(1,oriprice.length));

    var priceTwo = "$" + (priceOne * .70).toFixed(2);

    console.log(priceTwo)
```

```html
<span id="price">$59.00 </span>
```

The problem is that your priceOne was `NaN` after parsed. Try to use subString to remove the first `$` sign, and since it's a decimal amount, instead of using `parseInt`, use `parseFloat` and after calculating the 70% of it, apply `toFixed` on it

Comment: Can you clarify how you would select the value from the <span>?

Comment: Thanks! I am seeing some progress

Comment: @Sam: Do mark as answer  for any of the solution proposed that you think best answered as a reference for others who may encounter this issue in future, thanks

Comment: Actually, I am seeing an Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null

Comment: Try to check my solution to see if my `span ` element is exactly the same as yours? If you click the `Run code snippet` it clearly works

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript isn't able to parse strings to numbers if they have a string in it for whatever reason.

```js
var price = document.getElementsByClassName('price')[0];
price.innerHTML += '<br>$' + (parseFloat(price.innerHTML.replace('$', ''))*0.7).toFixed(2);
```

```html
<span class="price">$59.00</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions

```
var priceOne = document.querySelector(".price").innerHTML;
// Use regular expression to strip out all non-numbers
var re = /\.\d+|\d\/\d|\d/g 
var result = priceOne.match(re).join('');
//if in the united states, use this, else look on MDN for the correct formatting
document.querySelector(".price").innerHTML = (result*.7).toLocaleString("en-US",{style:"currency",currency:'USD'})
```